# 1000Base Fiber Switch to 100Base Fiber NIC (Desktop PC)

Tags: cisco, nic, fiber

Setting up an office space with some ACE Vision U6601 Desktop PCs. The current switch is a Cisco switch pushing 1000 M/bits and the PC fiber NICs only go up to 100 Full Duplex. Directly connecting the fiber to the endpoint leads to the switch not seeing the desktop; we tried forcing the switch down to 100 but as soon as the SFP and fiber are jacked in, it reverts to 1000. Is there anything that can be done to make these devices talk? We have a handful of Media Converters but are trying not to use them because of our available power space.

Could this issue be caused by an out of date driver? Would 100base SFPs work in this switch? Not sure the budget allows for a new switch pushing 100. The test PC connected through Media converter which is great as a temp fix but more difficult as a long term solution. Looking for ideas on how to get this working; any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Typically SFPs and SFP interfaces are single speed. Check the datasheet for your Cisco to see if it will support a 100Mb sfp.